# Flask-Bootstrap render_pagination() not changing to active page

Tags: python, flask, pagination, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-bootstrap

I am using Flask-Bootstrap's [`render_pagination`](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/sqlalchemy.html) macro. When I click the page numbers, it changes the URL to have `page=2`, but when the page re-renders, the results and page are still for page 1. How do I change the page and results when using `render_pagination`?

```
@app.route('/results')
def results(filename, page=1):
    logs = Logs.query.paginate(page)
    return render_template('results.html', logs=logs)
```

```
{% from "bootstrap/pagination.html" import render_pagination %}

{% for log in logs.items %}
    {{ log }}
{% endfor %}

{{ render_pagination(logs) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Flask-Bootstrap only deals with the frontend, you need to implement pagination on the backend. It renders links to the current view while changing the `page` query arg. You need to access this arg from `request.args` in the view and use it when paginating your query, by passing it to [`query.paginate`](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/latest/api/#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.BaseQuery.paginate).

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/results')
def results():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1)
    query_results = Episodes.query.paginate(page=page)
    return render_template('results.html', query_results=query_results)
```